# EF Core - Cannot add object with composite key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Alright, I'm trying to make a Wishlist containing user favorite items, however when I try to add them to the user, EF doesn't even try to INSERT, no action.

Here is my FavoriteProduct model

```
  public class FavoriteProduct : BaseDeletableModel<int>
    {
        public string FashionNovaUserId { get; set; }
        public FashionNovaUser FashionNovaUser { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

```
builder.Entity<FavoriteProduct>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProductId, x.FashionNovaUserId });
```

Here's my user model

```
 public class FashionNovaUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FavoriteProduct> FavoriteProducts { get; set; }
```

Then through my service layer I'm trying to add the favoriteProduct to user's list

```
            var favoriteProduct = new FavoriteProduct
            {
                ProductId = id,
                FashionNovaUserId = user.Id
            };

            user.FavoriteProducts.Add(favoriteProduct);
            this.db.SaveChanges();
```

When I do that, there database table is not updated, nor it has any new entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `FashionNovaUser` and `Product` are many-to-many relationships, if you would like to add records of  `FavoriteProduct` in join table, just use

```
var favoriteProduct = new FavoriteProduct
        {
            ProductId = id,
            FashionNovaUserId = user.Id
        };

this.db.Add(favoriteProduct);//or this.db.FavoriteProduct.Add(favoriteProduct)
this.db.SaveChanges();
```